# How to generate xml code(just code) from a dynamic form(javascript/reactjs)

Tags: javascript, xml, reactjs

Using React, I want to generate XML code based on what user will input on the form. The form should be dynamic and should render inputs based on which type user picks.
I want to generate code similar to the following:

```
<map> 
 <input> 
   <fields> 
    <field> 
     <fieldname>recordid</fieldname> 
    </field> 
    <field> 
     <fieldname>originmodule</fieldname> 
    </field> 
   </fields> 
 </input> 
 <output> 
   <fields> 
    <field> 
     <fieldname>targetaction</fieldname> 
    </field> 
   </fields> 
 </output> 
</map>
```

Do you know any article or any idea on how to start it which can help me with this?

Comment: Did you solve it?